# What do recent (2018) polls show the British people want from Brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, public-opinion

I was looking at the Wikipedia article on [opinion polls for the UK general election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_next_United_Kingdom_general_election) to determine if there has been any shift in UK politics that might give any indication of the likely outcomes of Brexit, however, it seems not much has changed in those national poll results.

**What do recent polls show the British people want from Brexit?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could have a look at the Brexit page of Wikipedia: [Brexit - public opinion polling - post referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum#Post-referendum_polling) and its sub-sections: [Right/Wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum#Right/Wrong), [Remain/Leave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum#Remain/Leave), [Three-option referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum#Three-option_referendum), [Britain rejoining EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum#On_Britain_rejoining_the_EU), [Second referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum#Support_for_a_second_referendum).

One example (copied from [Brexit public opinion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit#Post-referendum_opinion_polling)):

[image]

Comment: That [further information link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum#Post-referendum_polling) should be the main one IMO. Probably with sublinks covering each of its subsections.

Comment: @hkBst You're right. I did that.

Answer (score 2):

[This looks like a good place to start](https://whatukthinks.org/eu/opinion-polls/uk-poll-results/).

The answer you get will depend to some extent on the time span covered, and also the precise question that was asked - comparing "Should the United Kingdom remain a member of the European Union, or leave the European Union?" with "If there was a referendum on Britain’s membership of the EU, how would you vote?" shows some interesting differences.

There's another confounding factor on that page, as it lists different polling organisations along the same timeline, but hovering over the data will let you see what you're looking at.